# How to Formulate the given Linear programming program

Tags: linear-programming

> Chemlabs produce the domestic cleaning solutions $A$ and $B$ by processing the raw materials for $I$ & $II$. The processing of $1$ unit of raw material $I$ costs $\text{Rs. }80$ and produces $0.5$ units of solution $A$ and $0.5$ units of solution $B$.
>   Moreover, the processing of $1$ unit of raw material $II$ costs $\text{Rs. }50$ & produces $0.4$ units of solution $A$ and $0.6$ units of solution $B$.
>   The daily demand for solution $A$ lies between $10$ and $15$ units and that for solution $B$ lies between $12$ & $20$ units. Formulate the L.P.P.

Answer:

Let $x$ and $y$ be no. of units of raw material $I$ and $II$ to be processed respectively.

The objective function is $$\min z = 80x +50y.$$

Since the demand for solution $A$ lies between $10$ and $15$ units,

$$ 10 \le 0.5 x + 0.4x \le 15 \tag{1}$$

Since the demand for solution $B$ lies between $12$ and $20$ units,

$$ 12 \le 0.5 y+ 0.6 y \le 20 \tag{2}$$

Total LPP is $$\min z = 80x+50y $$
subject to

$$ 10 \le 0.9x \le 15$$
$$ 12 \le 1.1y \le 20$$
$$x, y \ge 0.$$

Is this formulation correct? Or I misunderstood the problem.

Comment: Why this question has not got any response?

Comment: Should I post this question in other community? If yes,to which community?

Comment: If it is typeset in MathJax and it has less words, perhaps it'll be better.
Since they don't know how to [search least-viewed unanswered questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/417779).

Answer (score 0):

If I represent the given constraints using two tables, the formulation for this cost minimization problem will be clear.

\begin{array}{crrrr}
\text{raw material} & \text{cost per unit} & \text{product $A$} & \text{product $B$} & \text{number of units processed} \\
I & \text{Rs. 80} & 0.5 & 0.5 & x \\
II & \text{Rs. 50} & 0.4 & 0.6 & y
\end{array}

From the above table, we can see that the amount of solutions $A$ and $B$ produced are $0.5x + 0.4y$ and $0.5x + 0.6y$ respectively.

\begin{array}{crrrr}
\text{product} & \text{number of units produced} & \text{min. daily demand} & \text{max. daily demand} \\
A & 0.5x + 0.4y & 10 & 15 \\
B & 0.5x + 0.6y & 12 & 20
\end{array}

Hence, the LPP should be formulated as

$$\min z= 80x + 50y$$
subject to
\begin{align}
0.5x + 0.4y &\ge 10 \\
0.5x + 0.4y &\le 15 \\
0.5x + 0.6y &\ge 12 \\
0.5x + 0.6y &\le 20.
\end{align}